# Regular expression in php with only allowed characters

Tags: php, regex

i got a problem with my regular expresion.i want to set allowed characters only  a-zA-Z and -
its work  but has one bug. if i insert string like this - "4567" it is returning false 
but if i inserting string like this - "4567PA" it returning true.

```
   if(!preg_match("/^[a-z-]+$/i", $string)) return false;
   else return true;
```

Comment: According to my tests, "4567PA" does not return any matches...

Comment: Don't know preg_match() but `^[a-z-]+$` won't match `4567PA`

Comment: Seems the same to me: http://3v4l.org/KH7Qp

Comment: BTW, please write this sanely as `return preg_match(...);` instead of your doubly negated `return return not true false`.

Comment: You should escape the `-` in the character class as it has special meaning, so use this: `[a-z\-]`

Comment: @MikeBrant as long as the `-` is the last character in a character class it is fine not to escape it. `[+-]` is fine, `[-+]` is not.

Comment: @OGHaza - `[-+]` is ok too. I think the dash literal can go anywhere in a character class where it is not interpreted as a range operator, so `[a-z-A-Z]` should be equivalent to `[a-zA-Z-]`

Comment: @sln the thought did occur that that could be the case as I wrote it. Good info, just had a mess around in regexpal and it's much more flexible than I thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning false when there aren't any matches - `!preg_match(...)` - which isn't what you want ( I'm guessing ). Plus, the if/else isn't necessary since you're returning true/false which is what `preg_match` returns.

Try this:

```
return preg_match("/^[a-z-]+$/i", $string);
```

Comment: no its not helps ((((

Comment: With the above, both "4567PA" and "4567" return 0 whereas something like "ThisIsValid" returns 1 ... is that not what you wanted?

Comment: This definitely works, fyi you should remove either the `A-Z` or the `i` (case insensitive) flag.

Comment: Removed. Didn't even notice the `i` flag. Thanks.

Comment: sbeliv01 yes that what i want . i vant allowed characters onle a-zA-Z and -

Comment: So this does helps then? :)))